# Command line comparison of 2 directories using Beyond Compare or other tool

Tags: version-control, beyondcompare, file-comparison

I have 2 directories which I need to compare using a command line utility. There are 2 requirements:

1. Not to present equal files in the output - that is, I do not want even the names of the equal files to appear in the output
2. Possibility to ignore unimportant differences

I tried to use Beyond Compare 2 with rules comparison, but did not find an option to meet the first requirement, while with Beyond Compare 4 I did not succeed to meet the second requirement.

Does anyone know how to do this with Beyond Compare or other tool?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think even beyond compare 4 provides an option to show only the files with differences. But, you can ignore unimportant differences by using the /iu or /ignoreunimportant option.

Assuming you have the beyond compare environment paths configured, your command would look like:

```
bcomp /iu folder1/ folder2/
```

If there are sub folders you may want to use /expandall option too, to see the files in those sub folders.